# Why does eclipse IDE disable private and protected class creation radio buttons

Tags: java, eclipse

Just wondering what is the reason that an eclipse IDE prevents us to create private/protected classes if we try creating it doing a right click on the project and then "new>class>"?

As you can see the private and protected radio buttons are disabled in the following image.

[image]

Which characteristic feature of Java causes this to happen?

Comment: It doesn't. but those classes and the instantiating code must be in a scope where this is possible. This is not Eclipse related, this is just how Java is designed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you select the `Enclosing type` check-box in the `New Java Class` windows (and provide some existing class to be the enclosing one), Eclipse **will let** you select `protected` or `private` for modifier.

[image]

By default, the IDE will try to create a top-level class, which by specification cannot be `private` or `protected`.

Comment: when  "Enclosing Type" is checked : it saying "Name of enclosing type must be entered." So ?

Comment: `Enclosing Type` is the class where the `private`/`protected` class would be nested, because it cannot be a top-level one.

Comment: @kocko Why are they marking this Unclear? Was the question unclear to you too?

Answer (score 4):

Because you cannot have private/ protected classes as top-level class

you can have private/ protected classes like this

```
class You implements Me {

    private class S {

    }
    protected class E {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are they marking this Unclear? Was the question unclear to you too?

Comment: NO, it was clear to me, and as per my understanding i put my answer and up votes are saying my answer is appropriate!

Comment: can you help me getting this reopened?

Comment: I just gave the reason why we can't have  private/ protected classes as top-level class and that's why Eclipse might not allowing to do so. And I have also gave example whats the possible way to make private/ protected classes.

Comment: there's no point of having a top-level class as private as nothing would have access to it.